# Sas command to set VT Keys

Tags: sas, hotkeys

In sas there appear to be multiple sets of keys "KEYS < VT >" (viewtable) and "KEYS < DMKEYS >"

I can use the following command to set DMKEYS:

```
dm "keydef F9 'submit'";
```

But it only sets DMKEYS and not VT Keys.  Is there an equivalent command I can use to set VT Keys, the keys that are set while I'm in the viewtable view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface the keydef by a vt; first.  The following copies the next viewtable into both key spaces.

```
dm "keydef F2 'next Viewtable:; end'";

dm "vt; keydef F2 'next Viewtable:; end'";
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to manage keys is from Display Manager itself.  Activate the window you care about (such as Viewtable while displaying some dataset), then use the menu sequence "Tools -> Options -> Keys".  That will open a new window with all the current key definitions.

If you **really** want to programmatically assign function keys to the VT key list, you might need to dive into SCL programming.  Key definition files are objects in your `sasuser.profile` catalog.  The entry for Viewtable is named **vt.keys**.  It's been several years since I messed with SCL (or function key manipulation either) so I can't help you there.